# How to fix 'Error: Enum value' in strapi content type?

Tags: node.js, strapi

I'm creating a new content type in Strapi, and I set a duplicate enum value in a type called Promotion.  first value is 'fixed discount' second value is 'percentage discount'.

this error has frozen my local installation, and I don't know how fix this issue. Any help in directing me to the proper resource where I might find the answer to fix this? This is my first time working with database, content types or code in general, so any help would be appreciated.

I've tried looking in the strapi Github threads, but my problem doesn't seem to be answered in a way that I understand. This is a local installation on my new Mac, which is running Node and NPM, and all the Strapi plugins are activated

I'm receiving an error message that reads:

> [2019-08-07T22:47:48.212Z] debug ⛔️ Server wasn't able to start properly.
>
> [2019-08-07T22:47:48.213Z] error Error: Enum value "ENUM_PROMOTION_TYPE.discount" can only be defined once.

I would like to be able to start strapi and fix the error, or at least avoid this in the future

Answer (score 0):

it seems like if you uninstall GraphQL, and run 'strapi build' it removes the dependancies and resets the database without the error.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use spaces un an enum value.
The correct usage is to set "keys" that match displayed string in your front end application.
You don't have to set the value you will display.
So for example:

- `fixed` as enum value has to match `Fixed discount` in your front end application
- `percentage` as enum value has to match `Percentage discount`

We fixed it in `develop` branch (for the next release) to allow only `^[A-Za-z][_0-9A-Za-z]*$`